# How to get Transaction Submitter in Hyperledger Fabric chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

Currently I'm working with Hyperledger Fabric chaincode and trying to get at least any info regarding current user who invokes/queries chaincode. 
How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the lib [cid](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid) is what you are searching for. The functions GetID and GetMSPID are super helpful to distinguish between the callers.

Here is an example on how to use it in go

```
msp, err := cid.GetMSPID(stub)
if err != nil {
    return false
}
```

This returns the name of the MSP and you can act depending on the result you get. You can even use this to give access to certain functions by MSPID.

Comment: Thank a lot, Kajuken. That looks like it is what I need.

Comment: @TiếnThànhNguyễn Glad i could help. An upvote is appreciated! :)

Comment: Is there a way to get the user who submitted the transaction? Or only if you provide it explicitly during the transaction submission?